# Compare get curl request headers using bash script

Tags: bash

I want to create a script that compares the value of specific get request headers.

So far script content is this:

```
var=$(curl -I -s http://myhost.local | grep X-Magento-Cache-Debug | awk {'print $2'})

if [ "$var" = "HIT" ]; then
  echo "OK"
else    
  echo "NOK"
  exit 2
fi
```

So using this script I want to compare the value of `X-Magento-Cache-Debug`. The problem is that the script always prints `NOK` regardless the value.

It looks like the string comparison here fails although when i `echo` the `var` value i get the desired content.

Any ideas will be helpful thanks.

Comment: Of couse `var != HIT`, correct?

Comment: Just replace `"var"` with `"$var"`…

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing the literal string `var` to the literal string `HIT`. The comparision would always be false.

If you want to compare the **content** of the variable `var` for equality it would be

```
[ "$var"  =  HIT ]
```

However, this would be false if the output of your pipe does not consist just of the word `HIT`, but much more text.

If you want to know, whether the content of the variable contains the substring *HIT* somewhere, this would be

```
[[ $var == *HIT* ]]
```

Another possibility would be to let `grep` do the job:

```
if curl -I -s http://myhost.local | grep X-Magento-Cache-Debug | grep -wF HIT 
then
  ....
fi
```

Comment: very greppy :) I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative 1:

Test your condition directly in awk:

```
curl -sI http://www.stackoverflow.com \
  | awk '/Connection/ { if ($2 ~ /keep-alive/) { exit 0; } } END { exit 1; }'
```

Alternative 2:

Use safer and more flexible pattern matching with `[[ =~ ]]`

```
$ conn=$(curl -sI http://www.stackoverflow.com | awk '/Connection/ { print $2 }')
$ [[ $conn =~ keep ]] && echo KEEP
KEEP
```

or ... `if [[ $conn =~ keep ]]; then foobar ; fi`